# Ireland student visa after UK tier 4 refused

Tags: united-kingdom, student-visa, ireland

I was refused a tiers 4 visa to the UK and any application will be automatically refused under a general ground refusals 320 (7A) (7B) using false document.

Now I would like to make an appeal because it may harm any future application and also the document in question was not fake it was an administrative error that I can provide in my administrative review.

the question is if I am accepted by Irish University and apply for a student visa would this previous refusal be prejudicial to the next application?

Comment: Many countries ask something like "have you ever been refused a visa or deported from any country" in the applications, to which you should definitely not lie (because they will find out). That said, if your refusal was on the grounds of admin error *and you can prove it* definitely do that ASAP, and I would wait for this before making my new application.

Answer (score 2):

It could be held against you. Most countries of the world ask for details on previous refusals of visas or entry. Although they normally can't find out the specific details unless you sign a release, you can never be certain of what information sharing agreements might exist, especially among neighboring countries that already have travel agreements in place. This doesn't necessarily mean an automatic refusal in every case. But it will draw extra scrutiny and "give them an excuse" if they find anything at all, however trivial or normally easily resolved, to refuse you yet again.

La femme Cosmique's recommendation is correct in my opinion. Fight it if it is winnable and get your record clean.

Comment: Thank you I will do so anyway if I win I will apply for Ireland if not there are some countries without visa requirement for me and they are among the best in education.